# Perfromance optimization for SpringbootMongoDBKafka streaming application

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, apache-kafka

Arch of app--

Event sent to --> [Consumer1 --> ABCService --> MongoRepos(Get,Post) --> Producer ]
[Consumer2 --> XYZService --> MongoRepos(Get,PUT) --> Producer ]
Service layer has 2 service class --:

1. ABCService = Pulls the events coming to consumer1 and, perform save operation
2. XYZService = Pulls the events coming to consumer2( which listens to 5 topics) and, perform update operation . So 5 update operation

Total MongoOperations in 1 flow= 2 Get,1 Save, 5 Put

Average time taken from consumer to producer in 1 flow is 1000ms

How can we improve the performance of the app, since its a major issue for us now?

Comment: Have you compared to using MongoDB sink connector?

Comment: Can this be used in SpringBootKafka application ? Or it can be used only in cloudlfow , apache flink applications? Not sure about its implementation.

Comment: [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/concepts.html) is a standalone framework / executable - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/v1.7/sink-connector/